# Packetbeat does not point to a write index

Tags: elasticsearch, elk, ilm

I tried to edit packetbeat Policy, and then from index management on Kibana I removed the policy from that index and then added it again (to take on consideration the new configuration),
unfortunately I a getting a `lifecycle error`

```
illegal_argument_exception: rollover target [packetbeat-7.9.2] does not point to a write index
```

[image]

I tried to run :

```
PUT packetbeat-7.9.2-2020.11.17-000002
{
  "aliases": {
    "packetbeat-7.9.2": {
      "is_write_index": true
    }
  }
}
```

But I got the error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "resource_already_exists_exception",
        "reason" : "index [packetbeat-7.9.2-2020.11.17-000002/oIsVi0TVS4WHHwoh4qgyPg] already exists",
        "index_uuid" : "oIsVi0TVS4WHHwoh4qgyPg",
        "index" : "packetbeat-7.9.2-2020.11.17-000002"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "resource_already_exists_exception",
    "reason" : "index [packetbeat-7.9.2-2020.11.17-000002/oIsVi0TVS4WHHwoh4qgyPg] already exists",
    "index_uuid" : "oIsVi0TVS4WHHwoh4qgyPg",
    "index" : "packetbeat-7.9.2-2020.11.17-000002"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Could you tell me how Can I solve this issue please ?

Thanks for your help